# Custom annotation showing same image for all different types of POI's

Tags: swift, location, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I need to show different annotation for different cat_ID on map. in this question i am including only two categories .

```
    let item = json["data"].arrayValue
    var count = 0
    initMK()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    while count < item.count{
        let lat = item[count]["comp_lat"].stringValue
        let lng = item[count]["comp_lng"].stringValue

        if item[count]["ct_id"].stringValue == "783"{
            self.state = "Jachthavens"
            let poi = MKPointAnnotation()
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude: Double(lng)!)
            poi.coordinate = coordinates
            poi.title = item[count]["comp_name_pub"].stringValue
            poi.subtitle = "Jachthavens"
            //poi.id
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(poi)
            self.mapView.reloadInputViews()


        }else if item[count]["ct_id"].stringValue == "788"{

            self.state = "Watersportwinkels"
            let poi = MKPointAnnotation()
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude: Double(lng)!)
            poi.coordinate = coordinates
            poi.title = item[count]["comp_name_pub"].stringValue
            poi.subtitle = "Watersportwinkels"
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(poi)
            self.mapView.reloadInputViews()
            }
            count = count + 1
            }
         }
```

/////////  This is my viewForAnnotation method for setting different images problem comes in only if (state == "Watersportwinkels") and (state == "Jachthavens"). In result i can see only "Jachthavens"  Image on my map but details on info window is correct .

let identifier = "MyPin"

```
    if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    let detailButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)

    // Reuse the annotation if possible
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

    if annotationView == nil
    {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        if(state == "track")
        {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "startpin")
        }
        else if(state == "pause")
        {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "pausepin")
        }
        else if(state == "stop")
        {
         annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "endpin")
        }else if (state == "Jachthavens") {
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "jachthavenpin")
                let deleteButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
                deleteButton.frame.size.width = 35
                deleteButton.frame.size.height = 35
                deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "jachthaven"), forState: .Normal)
                deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.infoClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
                annotationView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation



        }else if (state == "Watersportwinkels"){
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "watersportwinkelspin")
            let deleteButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            deleteButton.frame.size.width = 35
            deleteButton.frame.size.height = 35
            deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "watersportwinkels"), forState: .Normal)
            deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.infoClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            annotationView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }

    }
    else
    {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try to change:

```
}else if  {
```

into:

```
else if(state == "Jachthavens")
```

**update:**

check subtitle instead of state:

```
if annotationView == nil {

    annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

    if(annotationView.subtitle == "track") {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "startpin")
    } else if(annotationView.subtitle == "pause") {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "pausepin")
    } else if(annotationView.subtitle == "stop") {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "endpin")
    } else if (annotationView.subtitle == "Jachthavens") {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "jachthavenpin")
        let deleteButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        deleteButton.frame.size.width = 35
        deleteButton.frame.size.height = 35
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "jachthaven"), forState: .Normal)
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.infoClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        annotationView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    } else if (annotationView.subtitle == "Watersportwinkels") {
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "watersportwinkelspin")
        let deleteButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        deleteButton.frame.size.width = 35
        deleteButton.frame.size.height = 35
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "watersportwinkels"), forState: .Normal)
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.infoClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        annotationView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

} else {
    annotationView!.annotation = annotation
}
```

Comment: That was my mistake in actual code i have written (state == "Jachthavens")

Comment: @KrishnaThakur I'm not sure I understand? code works now or? what happens when you change this?

Comment: Again same problem custom annotations are not changing as per the filter. Showing UIImage(named: "jachthavenpin") image . if (state == "Watersportwinkels")

Comment: after annotationView!.canShowCallout = true put: print(state) and run to see is state always "Jachthavens", to me it looks like you are setting some global variable state and it always had last state you read from Json

Comment: Yes you are right it always pint  "Jachthavens" so what should be the optional way